# Calendar day of month Android

Tags: java, android, loops, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I choose the starting date (example 31/01/2014) and ending date (example 31/12/2014), I insert a record every month. If I get the next month is February 28th, but then I always get 28 though March, April, etc. ..
How can I fix? I hope I explained

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

for(
  int i=0; 
  calendar1.getTime().before(calendar2.getTime()); 
  i++
) {
  calendar1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

  if (calendar1.getTime().before(calendar2.getTime())) {
    String strDate = sdf1.format(calendar1.getTime());
    cv.put(etableTable.DATE, strDate);  
    db.insert(etableTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to describe your problem a little more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you speak about class `GregorianCalendar` - Instead of `calendar1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)` try to also call following method as work-around:

```
static GregorianCalendar moveToEndOfMonth(GregorianCalendar gcal) {
  gcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1); // moving to some day of next month
  gcal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // moving to first day of current month
  gcal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // moving to last day of previous month
}
```

So your final code should look like:

```
calendar1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
moveToEndOfMonth(calendar1);
```

Why? The analysis of @DavidCAdams is right, see his answer.

Comment: I can not change the code according to your suggestion. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: @user2976522 you just have to add the call `moveToEndOfMonth(calendar1);` behind your line `calendar1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);` And of course you need to define your helper method `moveToEndOfMonth(GregorianCalendar)` anywhere else in your class, but that is just basic java.

Comment: sorry, I was confused. your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Where are you creating the calendar objects? Since you are incrementing the MONTH, and it is January 30,  you get February 28 for the next month, since next month only has 28 days in it. There is no Feb 30, 2014. Thereafter, when you increment the month, you get March 28, April 28, etc. etc.

Comment: Hello, I'm interested in your response and I ask you, if a user clicks on January 31 and 12 want to insert records for that day, I insert a control that checks how many days has the following month? or is there an easier way?